# "The number of Xs" - why no article?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, definite-articles

Looking at [Why not add ‘the’ before the last ‘steps’ word?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/278313/why-not-add-the-before-the-last-steps-word?noredirect=1#comment519818_278313) as recently asked on ELL, I was struck by the realisation that it's very difficult to find contexts where we would include *both* articles in noun phrases of the general form *the **number** of the [things, steps, whatever]*. But there's no such restriction with other "attributes", such as *the **colour** of the steps, the **size** of the steaks, the **age** of the mountains,...*

> 1: *Find the **average length of words** in this sentence*  (fine)
> 2: *Find the **average length of the words** in this sentence*  (also fine)
> 3: *Find the **number of words** in this sentence*  (fine)
> 4: *Find the **number of the words** in this sentence*  (DOESN'T WORK)

Is there any identifiable reason why ***number*** should work like this? Are there any *other* "attribute" words (apart from ***number*** and near-synonymous ***quantity***) that are similarly "averse" to being attached to a plural noun phrase prefaced by the definite article?

Comment: Not an answer, but 'the number of the ...' is rare and one main application is 'the number of the beast', where 'number' means 'numerical label' rather than 'total population' ('population' in the 'how many altogether?' sense). Perhaps the article was dropped to disambiguate. Though you'd need 'numbers' in the slightly more usual 'the numbers of the missing lifeboats were 3 and 22'.

Comment: Probably influenced by the old idiomatic expression ***“a number of”*** which is typically followed by a noun without article. https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+number+of

Comment: From comments on the other question, "quantity" seems to work like "number" for me. I had missed the "average length of steps" form you mention here. Maybe if "the ____ of" can't refer individually, we reject it as odd in a phrase that could be used to mean individually, even when it's used to mean collectively?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, as soon as I see ***the number of the...*** I'm already thinking ***...Beast*** regardless of whatever (plural) noun might *actually* follow. (Of course, as a fully signed-up Satanist, what I'm *really* thinking is "Ooh! Please Sir! **I** know the answer! It's **666** :)

Comment: 'Find the percentage[/fraction] of words in this sentence having more than two syllables.' // 'Note the frequency of words beginning with a vowel in this sentence.' / 'Note the scarcity/lack[/abundance?] of words of over two syllables in this sentence.' These are fixed phrases, I'd say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: To me, *percentage* and *fraction* there are on a par with my example *average length* (I can take or leave the article with those; it's not like *number*, where I don't seem to have a choice). But *scarcity, lack, abundance* - they look like yet a *'nother* different ball game!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is, of course, if you give literal credence to a second century dream sequence allegory to which we have largely lost the key. Personally I'd dump Revelations and  replace it with Pilgrim's Progress which is a seventeenth century dream sequence allegory to which we still, largely, have the key. It's still old but it's 1500 years newer than Revelations.

Comment: @BoldBen: You're quite right, obviously. Apart from a few "meaninglessly memorable" elements that somehow stuck with me over the decades (number of the beast, four horsemen), I don't care much about the "ramblings" of Revelations. But Pilgrim's Progress was a fantastic spiritual journey into "other-worldliness" for me as a lad, before I moved on to getting something similar from sci-fi and the Chariots of the Gods fad we had back in the 60s and 70s